# отформатировать строку

Tags: php, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в PHP строку вида "5 700 Тг." сделать вида "5700" ?

Пробовал str_replace(' ', '', $str), результат  = 5 700Тг., то есть проблема в пробеле между 5 и 7
также пробовал через регулярку preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $str), результат = 5 700Тг.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не заменяется, потому что там у вас стоит не пробел, а [неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB) с кодом символа 160.

И я не пойму, зачем вы пытаетесь удалить пробел, если задача удалить все, кроме цифр?

```php
preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Потому что всё, кроме этого неразрывного пробела удаляется, я знаю как это сделать :) Ваш ответ помог мне, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:
preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', '5 700 Тг.');